# Connect to embedded ActiveMQ from different Spring Boot project

Tags: spring-boot, activemq-classic

I have a Spring Boot project configured with ActiveMQ. There is another Spring Boot project which is acting as the consumer of that ActiveMQ instance. When I tried to connect it always shows the error message

> retrying using FixedBackOff{interval=5000, currentAttempts=113,
>   maxAttempts=unlimited}. Cause: Could not connect to broker URL:
>   tcp://localhost:61616. Reason: java.net.ConnectException: Connection
>   refused (Connection refused)

Following is my configurations in the consumer project.

```
@Configuration
@EnableJms
public class Config {

    @Autowired
    ConnectionFactory connectionFactory;

    @Autowired
    MessageListener messageListener;

    @Bean
    public ActiveMQQueue getQueue(){
        return new ActiveMQQueue("my.queue");
    }

    @Bean
    public ActiveMQConnectionFactory getActiveMQConnectionFactory(){
        ActiveMQConnectionFactory activeMQConnectionFactory = new ActiveMQConnectionFactory();
        activeMQConnectionFactory.setBrokerURL("tcp://localhost:61616");
        //activeMQConnectionFactory.setBrokerURL("vm://localhost");
        return activeMQConnectionFactory;
    }

    @Bean
    public JmsTemplate getJmsTemplate(){
        return new JmsTemplate(activeMQConnectionFactory());
    }

    @Bean
    public MessageListenerContainer getContainer() {
        DefaultMessageListenerContainer container = new DefaultMessageListenerContainer();
        container.setSessionAcknowledgeMode(Session.CLIENT_ACKNOWLEDGE);
        container.setConnectionFactory(connectionFactory);
        container.setMessageListener(messageListener);
        container.setDestinationName("my.queue");
        return container;
    }
```

How can I connect to the embedded ActiveMQ running on the other project? Both projects are running on same vm.

Comment: Is the embedded ActiveMQ broker actually configured to listen for connections on `localhost:61616`?

Comment: it uses default configurations.

Comment: If you're using the default configuration that may be the problem. I'm not sure if it has a connector for tcp clients on `61616` by default. I think it only has a vm connector.

Comment: @JustinBertram yes it only has the vm connector

Comment: Then you should add a tcp connector to the ActiveMQ configuration so clients outside the JVM can actually connect to it.